# cloudwatch metric filter alert with logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

We are using cloudwatch metrics filter and setup alarm and send notification through SNS - Email.

We are wondering if it is possible to also see logs that triggers the alarm in the email? or is it possible to do so with the help with a custom lambda function?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Locally, you may try to have the following set up.

1. CloudWatch *Alarm*
2. *SNS-log-reader* with lambda as a subscriber
3. *SNS-send-mails* with e-mails as a subscriber

So the logic would be - *Alarm* trigger *SNS-log-reader*. Then lambda which is mapped to *SNS-log-reader can read the logs from LogGroup, build the message in needed format and send to e-mail/s via *SNS-send-mails* (or Simple Email Service (Amazon SES))